# Deselected All by updatePickerInput shiny R

Tags: r, input, shiny, updates

I my shiny app I have few pickerInput elements. As a default nothing is selected.

```
pickerInput(
  inputId = "pickerInput1", 
  label = NULL, 
  choices = c("Yes", "No"), 
  options = list(
    `actions-box` = TRUE, 
    size = 12,
    `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
  ), 
  multiple = TRUE
)
```

The problem is that I have no idea how I can clear all of them (go to default value) after click on a special button. Unfortunately I propobly don't know how to use updatePickerInput. I tried:

```
  observeEvent(input$Clear_FilterButton,     {
    updatePickerInput(session, "pickerInput1", selected = NULL)
  })
```

but it doesn't work :( Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets`, setting `actions-box` to `TRUE` should build **Select All** & **Deselect All** buttons by default. You don't need `updatePickerInput`. Click on your `pickerInput` to see these buttons.

Please refer to the documentation for additional details:
https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets

**Update following up your comment:**

Your comment made the question more clear. You can simply use `selected = ""` instead of `selected = NULL`. Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "pickerInput1", 
    label = NULL, 
    choices = c("Yes", "No"), 
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE, 
      size = 12
    ), 
    multiple = TRUE
  ),

  actionButton(
    inputId = "Clear_FilterButton",
    label = "Clear"
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$Clear_FilterButton, {
    updatePickerInput(
      session, 
      "pickerInput1", 
      selected = ""
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I know about those buttons. But the problem is that I have about 30 pickerInputs in my app and I would like to clear them all using one click on actionButton. That is why I have to use updatePickerInput. Can you help me with this task?

Comment: @dasti74; You can use `selected = ""` instead of `selected = NULL`. I updated the answer accordingly.